# Doctrine & Symfony2 - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'x-y' for key 'PRIMARY

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixture

I am creating some `Fixtures` in Symfony2 using Doctrine. I get the following error:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '206-411' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

when I try to persist a many-to-many unidirectional association.
I understand the error, but I'm confused: isn't obvious that some IDs are duplicate in a many-to-many relationship? 
If I'm wrong please correct me. I put my code below, any clarification is welcome.

**Fixture file:**

```
namespace sociaLecomps\SuperBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class LoadAssociationsData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null){
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');

        /*
         * COURSE - STUDENT ASSOCIATION
         */

        $courses = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM sociaLecompsSuperBundle:Course c')->getResult();
        $students = $em->createQuery('SELECT s FROM sociaLecompsSuperBundle:Student s')->getResult();

        $i=0;
        for($j=0; $j<count($courses); $j++){

            $course = $courses[$j];

            //here I'm adding two different students to the same course
            $s = array($students[$i], $students[$i++]);
            $course->setSubscribedStudents($s);
            $em->persist($course);

            $i++;
        }
        $manager->flush();

    }
}
```

**Relationship declaration in Course class:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Student")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relation_course_student",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     **/
    private $subscribed_students;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->subscribed_students = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Entities Student and Course are created, also with `Fixtures`, before attempting to create the association.
If I try to insert only one student per course it all works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was the stupidest thing. 
I replaced:

```
$s = array($students[$i], $students[$i++]);
```

with

```
$s = array($students[$i], $students[++$i]);
```

Since it was a **post-increment**, the second insertion tried to put the same student into the database, resulting with an exact row duplicate.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I see that your courses entities already exist because you're fetching them directly from the database (`$courses = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM sociaLecompsSuperBundle:Course c')->getResult();`). So you shouldn't be trying to persist the entity a second time. I suggest you use `merge()` this way:

```php
$em->merge($course);
```

**Note 1:**
I see you're using Doctrine fixtures here and that students and courses have already been created. If they have been created through a Doctrine fixture as well consider using the `addReference` and `getReference` methods. Example here: https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/blob/master/README.md#sharing-objects-between-fixtures

**Note 2:** Also you don't have a **cascade** option set into your `subscribed_students` association. Since the students already exist should not be an issue. Otherwise you can either set the cascade option or run a `merge`|`persist` on the student entity as well.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tips ^^